# Dynamic Drop Down List using loop

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have database named as 'ecc' with table named as 'client'
table client has many fields, consider one of them named as ProjectManager
I want to display data of ProjectManager in select drop down list.
More data can be added to ProjectManager so loop is necessary.

please can some one help by writing the code for the same...
thanks for help in advance..

Comment: show the code u currently have

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is a sample code for mysqli:
I did not given that a try but should be working. You need to replace values for username, password for db and what value you need in your select options

```
<?php
// Connect db
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','ecc');

// check if error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Can not connect to DB error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ProjectManager FROM client");

echo '<select name="project_manager">';
echo '<option value="">-select project manager-</option>';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ProjectManager'].'">'.$row['ProjectManager'].'</option>';
}  
echo '</select>';

// Frees memory
$results->free();
// close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: any error in that ?

Comment: thank you its working @shaile